# Getting the WCF SessionID in the Client

Tags: c#, wcf, soa

I am writing a WCF client and am using a ChannelFactory to create my proxy to my Service:

```
    [ServiceContract]
    interface Service {

        [OperationContract]
        void Operation();
    }


var proxy = ChannelFactory<MyServiceInterface>.CreateChannel(
            new BasicHttpBinding(),
            new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8000/"));
```

How would I go about getting the SessionID? The proxy only has the basic Object methods as well as the ones defined in MyServiceInterface.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: we can't see the way you have defined Sessions in MyServiceInterface

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In your WCF Service file (.svc) add the following:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string SessionId()
    {
        return OperationContext.Current.SessionId;
    }
}
```

In your WCF Service interface add the following:

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    string SessionId();
}
```

In your client, do the following:

```
    ChannelFactory<IService1> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(
        new WSHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:4213/Service1.svc"));
    IService1 proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

    Console.WriteLine(proxy.SessionId());

    ((IClientChannel)proxy).Close();
    factory.Close();

    Console.Read();
```

By doing this you can get the proxy session created at service side. Just to know, when `((IClientChannel)proxy).Close();` and `factory.Close();` were invoked, then proxy will get new session.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but I don't see the .SessionId() on the proxy object.

Comment: Should I create an operation that polls the server for the sessionID?

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't what I was looking for to make the SessionId() an OperationContract. If, instead of using the ChannelFactory, I created my own proxy by extending ClientBase<>, and that gave me access to the InnerChannel.SessionId property.